# How to use shared preference to save user selected language with bloc approach

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, bloc

I have a bloc cubit to change language from English to Arabic and when I click on change button the language change successfully , but when I'm closing the app and return again the default language is return to work .

this is my language cubit

```
class LocaleCubit extends Cubit<LocaleState> {
  LocaleCubit() : super(SelectedLocale(Locale('ar')));

  void toArabic() => emit(SelectedLocale(Locale('ar')));

  void toEnglish() => emit(SelectedLocale(Locale('en')));
}
```

and this is the usage in main

```
supportedLocales: AppLocalizationsSetup.supportedLocales,
            localizationsDelegates:
                AppLocalizationsSetup.localizationsDelegates,
            localeResolutionCallback:
                AppLocalizationsSetup.localeResolutionCallback,
            locale: localeState.locale,
```

so can anyone know how to use shared preference to save the language value when user open the app again .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject the sharedPreferences object into the Cubit.

```
class LocaleCubit extends Cubit<LocaleState> {
  final SharedPreferences _preferences;
LocaleCubit(this._preferences) : super(SelectedLocale(Locale(_preferences.getString('locale')??'ar')));
// Here we initialize the object to the last saved locale and default to 'ar' if there is none


// Method that saves and emits the new locale
  void _changeLocale(String locale) { 
_preferences.setString('locale',locale);
emit(SelectedLocale(Locale(locale)));
}
  void toEnglish() => _changeLocale'en');
  void toArabic() => _changeLocale('ar');
}
```

Your Cubit has the same API as before , only that now the values are being saved on each state change, and the SharedPreferences must be passed to the constructor.

Comment: how to use it in main

Comment: i got this error The method 'getString' was called on null.

Answer (score 1):

To answer Mariam Younes's question to Stewie Griffin on how to use his implementation in main().

```
 main() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String language = prefs.getString('language') ?? "en";
  runApp(MyApp(language: language));
 }
```

As you can see we send the String language which can be fetched by any class after the fact.

If it is the first time the app has been launched it will launch in English after that it will launch in the selected language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setString` method of shared_preferences to save the selected language.

#### [setString](https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/setString.html)

> Saves a string value to persistent storage in the background.

```dart
Future<bool> saveLanguage(String langCode) async {
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   // Save the language
   return await prefs.setString('language', langCode);
}
```

When you want to retrieve the saved language:

#### [getString](https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/getString.html)

> Reads a value from persistent storage, throwing an exception if it's
> not a String.

```dart
Future<String?> getLanguage() async {
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   // Get the language using the key
   return await prefs.getString('language');
}
```

```dart
void toArabic() {
   emit(SelectedLocale(Locale('ar')));
   saveLanguage('ar');
}

void toEnglish() {
   emit(SelectedLocale(Locale('en')));
   saveLanguage('en');
}
```

Comment: how to use it in main